# how to create a left and right rotation function for an AVL tree

Tags: python-3.x, avl-tree

i'm trying to figure out how to rotate an AVL tree left and right around a pivot point ill call node. Thought process: new root must be the old roots left child. the old root then keeps its right child and then we must set its left child to temp which is the new roots old right child.

```
def rotate_right(self, node)

    new_root = node._left
    temp = new_root._right
    new_root._right = node 
    node._left = temp
    self._root = new_root
```

Comment: Looks good so far after the edit. What's your problem? (Hint try: with a simple tree)

Comment: my self._root value doesnt change to my new_root. should i set self._root = new_root?

Comment: @dhke i feel like i am losing values along the way. Because when i rotate my bst and then try and print the new roots left child it comes up with an error because it is a none type. when really it should be a value. It has no problem printing the right child of the new_root because the new_root._right has been assigned the old root which is node.

Comment: That is impossible to answer without the rest of your datastructure. I think it's customary to return the new root from the rotate function but it all depends on how you built your tree data structure in the first place.

Comment: when i print my AVL in preorder i get:

u
n
x
y
z

when i rotate right and print pre order again i get:

n
u
x
y
z
it should be n x u y z